# ASP.net MVC 3 adding arbitrary text to the end of an ActionLink

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, actionlink

Hi I have a question about Html.ActionLink.

Imagine:

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.title, "Singlet", new { id = item.blog_id })
```

produces http://[url]/[controller]/Singlet/[id]

But what if I want to suffix some more arbitrary data at the end? For example:

http://[url]/[controller]/Singlet/[id]/#comments

To jump to the comments div. I know I can just make the string myself with something like:

```
@( new HtmlString(String.Format("<a href=\"Blog/Singlet/{0}/#comments\">link to comments</a>", item.blog_id)) )
```

But I am hoping there is a cleaner way, perhaps with ActionLink?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe something like this might work:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    item.title, 
    "Singlet", 
    "Blog", 
    Request.Url.Scheme, 
    null, 
    "comments", 
    new { id = item.blog_id }, 
    null
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this instead:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Singlet", new { id = item.blog_id })#comments">@item.title</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this answer and see if it helps:

[Create a T4MVC ActionLink with url fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920983/create-a-t4mvc-actionlink-with-hash-pound-sign)

It looks like the feature was added in ASP.NET MVC 2, so it should be available in 3 as well. Here's the documentation for the `ActionLink` method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460522.aspx

Specifically, it looks like the `fragment` parameter is the one you're interested in.