# How can I include a bookmark/fragment in an ActionLink?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, bookmarks, actionlink

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Including an anchor tag in an asp.net mvc Html.ActionLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274586/including-an-anchor-tag-in-an-asp-net-mvc-html-actionlink)

The code : `@Html.ActionLink("Link", "Action", "Controller", new { id = Id } )`

For the moment I can generate links like this :

> *http://mywebsite/Controller/Action/Id*

I would like to generate a link like this :

> *http://mywebsite/Controller/Action/Id#divId*

But I can't edit the route/create another route.

What is the best solution?

Comment: There is similar post....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920983/create-a-t4mvc-actionlink-with-url-fragment

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use the [`proper overload`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460522%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) of the ActionLink helper:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    linkText: "Link",
    actionName: "Action",
    controllerName: "Controller",
    protocol: null,
    hostName: null,
    fragment: "divId",
    routeValues: new { id = Id },
    htmlAttributes: null
)
```

will generate:

```
<a href="/Controller/Action/123#divId">Link</a>
```